# Add a filter to a method in the parent theme

Tags: plugins, hooks

I have a child theme with this filter:

```
function translate_subscribe_btn() {
    $new_form = str_replace('Subscribe', 'إشترك الآن', $form);
    return $new_form;
}

add_filter(array('Raymond_NewsletterWidget', 'get_widget_form'), 'translate_subscribe_btn');
```

The original method:
class Raymond_NewsletterWidget extends WP_Widget {

```
function __construct() {

    parent::__construct(false, $name = '@Raymond Newsletter', array('description' => 'Newsletter widget to add subscription forms on sidebars'), array('width' => '350px'));

}



static function get_widget_form( array $instance=array() ) {

    $options_profile = get_option('newsletter_profile');

    $placeholder =( isset( $instance['placeholder'] ) ) ? $instance['placeholder'] : __('Email','raymond');

    $email = is_email( $options_profile['email'] ) ? $options_profile['email'] : $placeholder;

    $form = NewsletterSubscription::instance()->get_form_javascript();



    $form .= '<form action="' . home_url('/') . '?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)" method="post">';

    // Referrer

    $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="nr" value="widget"/>';



    if ($options_profile['name_status'] == 2)

        $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-firstname" placeholder="'. esc_attr( $placeholder ) .'" type="text" name="nn" value="' . esc_attr($options_profile['name']) . '" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=\'\'" onblur="if (this.value==\'\') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p>';



    if ($options_profile['surname_status'] == 2)

        $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-lastname" placeholder="'. esc_attr( $placeholder ) .'" type="text" name="ns" value="' . esc_attr($options_profile['surname']) . '" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=\'\'" onblur="if (this.value==\'\') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p>';



    $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-email" type="email" placeholder="'. esc_attr( $placeholder ) .'" required name="ne" value="' . esc_attr( $email ) . '" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=\'\'" onblur="if (this.value==\'\') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p>';



    if (isset($options_profile['sex_status']) && $options_profile['sex_status'] == 2) {

        $form .= '<p><select name="nx" class="newsletter-sex">';

        $form .= '<option value="m">' . $options_profile['sex_male'] . '</option>';

        $form .= '<option value="f">' . $options_profile['sex_female'] . '</option>';

        $form .= '</select></p>';

    }



    // Extra profile fields

    for ($i = 1; $i <= NEWSLETTER_PROFILE_MAX; $i++) {

        if ($options_profile['profile_' . $i . '_status'] != 2)

            continue;

        if ($options_profile['profile_' . $i . '_type'] == 'text') {

            $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-profile newsletter-profile-' . $i . '" type="text" name="np' . $i . '" value="' . $options_profile['profile_' . $i] . '" onclick="if (this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value=\'\'" onblur="if (this.value==\'\') this.value=this.defaultValue"/></p>';

        }

        if ($options_profile['profile_' . $i . '_type'] == 'select') {

            $form .= '<p>' . $options_profile['profile_' . $i] . '<br /><select class="newsletter-profile newsletter-profile-' . $i . '" name="np' . $i . '">';

            $opts = explode(',', $options_profile['profile_' . $i . '_options']);

            for ($t = 0; $t < count($opts); $t++) {

                $form .= '<option>' . trim($opts[$t]) . '</option>';

            }

            $form .= '</select></p>';

        }

    }



    $lists = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= NEWSLETTER_LIST_MAX; $i++) {

        if ($options_profile['list_' . $i . '_status'] != 2)

            continue;

        $lists .= '<input type="checkbox" name="nl[]" value="' . $i . '"';

        if ($options_profile['list_' . $i . '_checked'] == 1)

            $lists .= ' checked';

        $lists .= '/>&nbsp;' . $options_profile['list_' . $i] . '<br />';

    }

    if (!empty($lists))

        $form .= '<p>' . $lists . '</p>';





    $extra = apply_filters('newsletter_subscription_extra', array());

    foreach ($extra as &$x) {

        $form .= "<p>";

        if (!empty($x['label']))

            $form .= $x['label'] . "<br/>";

        $form .= $x['field'] . "</p>";

    }



    if ($options_profile['privacy_status'] == 1) {

        if (!empty($options_profile['privacy_url'])) {

            $form .= '<p><input type="checkbox" name="ny"/>&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="' . $options_profile['privacy_url'] . '">' . $options_profile['privacy'] . '</a></p>';

        }

        else

            $form .= '<p><input type="checkbox" name="ny"/>&nbsp;' . $options_profile['privacy'] . '</p>';

    }



    if (strpos($options_profile['subscribe'], 'http://') !== false) {

        $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-submit" type="image" src="' . $options_profile['subscribe'] . '"/></p>';

    } else {

        $subscribe_text = 'Subscribe';
        /*if ( is_rtl() ) {
            $subscribe_text = 'إشترك الآن';
        }*/
        //$form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="' . $options_profile['subscribe'] . '"/></p>';
        $form .= '<p><input class="newsletter-submit" type="submit" value="' . $subscribe_text . '"/></p>';

    }

    // hide popup

    $form .= '<div class="tb-newsletter-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="hide_popup" id="tb-hide-popup"><span>' . esc_html__("Don’t show this popup again","raymond") .'</span></div>';



    $form .= '</form>';



    return $form;

}
```

}
The `get_widget_form` is a static method. Now, when I refresh the main page the button still has the same value '**Subscribe**', my question here, why the filter didn't change the value?

Comment: Would you update your question with the code from the parent theme that generates the button?

Comment: @DaveRomsey OK done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with init hook

```
add_action('init', 'child_theme_hooks');

function child_theme_hooks() {
    add_filter(array('Raymond_NewsletterWidget', 'get_widget_form'), 'translate_subscribe_btn');
}

function translate_subscribe_btn() {
    $new_form = str_replace('Subscribe', 'إشترك الآن', $form);
    return $new_form;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work even your logic looks right.